# Edit the current file and read from the edited line

Tags: awk, gawk

I am new to AWK/sed. I am reading a file that looks like the following, but it is rather HUGE with about 1500 records. Plus I'll be using this script on multiple such files:

```
Der263849500 Glazed glazed.xyz14@zyx.com
Cds274849540 Trover trover.xyz12@zyx.com
Abd 246738209 Sigma Sigma.xyz13@zyx.com
```

If you notice, the third record has a space between the first and the second field. I want that particular record to be rectified in the file itself. Also, post rectifying the line, the AWK code should process the rectified line again. The following is the code I'd tried -

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    edited=0
}
{
    if (match($1,"[A-Z][a-z][a-z]$")!=0) {
        temp = $1 $2
        newLine = temp
        for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) {
                if ($i != "") {
                    newLine = newLine " " $i
                }
            }
        print newLine
        FILRNAME[FNR]=newLine
        NR=NR-1
        edited=edited+1
    }
}
END {
    print "The number of lines edited is " edited
}
```

The above code prints the line as I want it, but there are no changes made to the file being read. What do I do?

Comment: Can you put a number to ballpark how HUGE the file is?  Can you also comment on what you would like to accomplish by reprocessing each line after an edit?  Is it to concatenate more leading fields together if there are more than 3 fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to change the file.

```
awk 'some commands' inputfile > tmp & mv tmp inputfile
```

This will replace source file with new content.

---

```
sed -i 'some code' file
```

`-i` would write back to original file.

Comment: No, I do not wish to change the file. The given example is a sample. But the actual file is HUGE. And there may be multiple such rectifications needed per file. So, changing the file may not be scalable.

Comment: I did read this `The above code prints the line as I want it, but there are no changes made to the file being read.` and reply on how to change the file.

Comment: 'FILRNAME[FNR]=newLine' - This line is supposed to write the edited record back into the file. Or that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: You can not write back to the same file as you are reading.  You need to go trough a temporary file, and then store it back to original file.

Comment: Is there no other way? not even with sed?

Comment: `sed -i` write back the new changes, but I think it does it in a prosess after all is done, like the `awk` i write above (after all is done)

Comment: Updated post with `sed` example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed command to make the changes in the same file by using below command:

```
sed -i '/^[A-Za-z]*[[:space:]]/ {s/\(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\)/\1\2 \3 \4/g}' filename
```

You can write the script to find the number of records changed in your file.